# Manuscript status changed immediately from "With the Editor" to "Decision in Process"

Tags: peer-review, editors, rejection

I submitted a manuscript in a journal (Springer) and after 3 days the status of my MS changed to "With the Editor" followed by "Decision in Process" after 5 days. My MS apparently did not undergo peer-review. Should I expect rejection on this stage?

Answer (score 4):

If the editor decided not to send the manuscript out for peer review, then the decision is almost certainly a desk rejection.

In theory, I suppose it might have gone out for peer review and just been an unusually speed process, but in practice that is extremely unlikely.

[The canonical journal workflow question may provide more detail if you wish](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/22733).

Comment: With the editor might be a kind of receipt. So that perhaps all ms submitted to that journal go through a Decision in progress stage?